# Strange behavior upgrading FSharp.Core with NuGet

Tags: f#, nuget

I have an F# project that uses FSharp.Core version 4.1.0. When I upgrade to version 4.1.12, NuGet adds the following files to my project's source code directory:

- `any/netstandard1.6/FSharp.Core.sigdata`
- `any/netstandard1.6/FSharp.Core.optdata`

I expect NuGet to add files under the `packages` directory, not directly into my project. Having these files appear alongside `.fs` files in the project's source code tree seems odd. Is this expected behavior? Can I safely delete these files (since copies presumably exist under `packages` as well)?

Here's an example of what I see:

[image]

Comment: related https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/pull/2884